# Delete subfolders after a given time interval

Tags: java, groovy

After a certain time interval(month) I want to delete the subfolders with content. Can someone help me to achieve this. The following code shows errors related to Iterator.

```
// Create a ref for closure
def dir
def yesterday = ( new Date() ).time - 1000*60*60*24    

//definition Closure    
dir = {
  while(it.hasNext()){
    it.eachDirRecurse( dir )
      println("Dir: " + it.canonicalPath)
    if(it.lastModified() <= yesterday)  
      it.deleteDir()
  }
}

// Apply closure
dir( new File("H:\\soapUI\\Adres\\") )
```

This is the Exception:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.hasNext() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: inspect(), getText(), getText(java.lang.String), setText(java.lang.String), setText(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), hashCode()\
at test$_run_closure1.doCall(test.groovy:8)
    at test.run(test.groovy:19)
```

Comment: A File is not an Iterator. It does not have the methods you attempt to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least couple of errors in your code...

- why do you do `it.hasNext()` on a File
- you call `it.eachDirRecurse` which will recurse down the whole tree, but you then call it again for every directory in that tree...

You are also going to have problems as you will remove a directory, but then `eachDirRecurse` will still try to walk down into that directory and throw a `FileNotFoundException`

I think you're going to have to not use `eachDirRecurse`

Assuming you are on Groovy 1.8 (you don't say), you can do something like this:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import static groovy.io.FileType.*

def yesterday = use( TimeCategory ) { new Date() - 1.day }

def deleteFoldersIn = { File f ->
  f.traverse( [ type:DIRECTORIES, postDir:{ d -> if( d.lastModified() < yesterday.time ) d.deleteDir() } ] ) { 
    println "Scanning $it"
  }
}

// Apply closure
deleteFoldersIn( new File( 'H:\\soapUI\\Adres\\' ) )
```

Here's the documentation for [TimeCategory](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html), [FileType](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/io/FileType.html) and [File.traverse()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse%28java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29)

Comment: Thnx a lot for the clear explanation, effort and time you take to help me. As a junior programmer i can learn a lot from people like you. For sure i will implement this.

Answer (score 0):

new File('dir').deleteDir() is recursive for me in groovy 1.8

there's magic in the drink!

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can use dir and deleteDir functionality.

[DeleteDir](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-deletedir-code-recursively-delete-the-current-directory-from-the-workspace): Recursively deletes the current directory and its contents. Symbolic links and junctions will not be followed but will be removed. To delete a specific directory of a workspace wrap the deleteDir step in a dir step.

```
dir('directoryToDelete') {
    deleteDir()
}
```